# Button Not Working When Change In 2nd Fragment From 1st Fragment

Tags: java, android

I Create a Hamburger But Here The Problem is that I added a Button in 1st Fragment But When I Change My Fragment in 2nd Fragment Then  Again I Change to 1st Fragment Then Button in 1st Fragment Does Not Work...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
ListView listView;
String[] items;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "Hey Check Out iNotes " + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow, R.id.nav_videolec, R.id.nav_musiczone)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    //Here We Have All Buttons------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

    Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button button6 = findViewById(R.id.button6);
    Button button7 = findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button button8 = findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Button button9 = findViewById(R.id.button9);
    Button button10 = findViewById(R.id.button10);
    Button button11 = findViewById(R.id.button11);
    Button button12 = findViewById(R.id.button12);
    Button button13 = findViewById(R.id.button13);
    Button button14 = findViewById(R.id.button14);
    Button button15 = findViewById(R.id.button15);
    Button button16 = findViewById(R.id.button16);
    Button button17 = findViewById(R.id.button17);
    Button button18 = findViewById(R.id.button18);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    button5.setOnClickListener(this);
    button6.setOnClickListener(this);
    button7.setOnClickListener(this);
    button8.setOnClickListener(this);
    button9.setOnClickListener(this);
    button10.setOnClickListener(this);
    button11.setOnClickListener(this);
    button12.setOnClickListener(this);
    button13.setOnClickListener(this);
    button14.setOnClickListener(this);
    button15.setOnClickListener(this);
    button16.setOnClickListener(this);
    button17.setOnClickListener(this);
    button18.setOnClickListener(this);
```

//  <------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

```
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent1.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent2.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent3.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent3);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent4.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent4);
            break;
        case R.id.button5:
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent5.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent5);
            break;
        case R.id.button6:
            Intent intent6 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent6.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent6);
            break;
        case R.id.button7:
            Intent intent7 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent7.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent7);
            break;
        case R.id.button8:
            Intent intent8 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent8.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent8);
            break;
        case R.id.button9:
            Intent intent9 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent9.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent9);
            break;
        case R.id.button10:
            Intent intent10 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent10.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent10);
            break;
        case R.id.button11:
            Intent intent11 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent11.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent11);
            break;
        case R.id.button12:
            Intent intent12 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent12.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent12);
            break;
        case R.id.button13:
            Intent intent13 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent13.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent13);
            break;
        case R.id.button14:
            Intent intent14 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent14.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent14);
            break;
        case R.id.button15:
            Intent intent15 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent15.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent15);
            break;
        case R.id.button16:
            Intent intent16 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent16.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent16);
            break;
        case R.id.button17:
            Intent intent17 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent17.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent17);
            break;
        case R.id.button18:
            Intent intent18 = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
            intent18.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent18);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: show some code how do you realize clicking

Comment: check out bro i upload it